# Unknown animator name: alpha

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Получаю такую ошибку (заголовок), код:

Переход:

```
} else if (settings.getInt(whatanim, 1) == 2){
                fTrans.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.activity_close_enter, R.anim.activity_open_enter);
            }
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    fTrans.replace(R.id.frame, tts)
                            .commit();
```

activity_close_enter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set android:zAdjustment="normal"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:interpolator="@anim/linear_out_slow_in" android:duration="250" android:fillBefore="true" android:fillAfter="true" android:fromAlpha="0.7" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:fillEnabled="true" />
</set>
```

activity_open_enter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set android:shareInterpolator="false" android:zAdjustment="top"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:interpolator="@anim/decelerate_quart" android:duration="200" android:fillBefore="false" android:fillAfter="true" android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:fillEnabled="true" />
    <translate android:interpolator="@anim/decelerate_quint" android:duration="350" android:fillBefore="true" android:fillAfter="true" android:fromYDelta="8.000004%" android:toYDelta="0.0" android:fillEnabled="true" />
</set>
```

Извините, если ответ уже есть или я туплю, я новичок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для фрагментов нужно использовать `ObjectAnimator`:

**activity_close_enter**

```
<set android:zAdjustment="normal" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator 
        android:propertyName="alpha" 
        android:interpolator="@anim/linear_out_slow_in" 
        android:duration="250" 
        android:fillBefore="true"
        android:fillAfter="true" 
        android:valueType="floatValue"
        android:valueFrom="0.7" 
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:fillEnabled="true" />
</set>
```

**activity_open_enter**

```
<set android:shareInterpolator="false" android:zAdjustment="top" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<objectAnimator
       android:propertyName="alpha" 
       android:interpolator="@anim/decelerate_quart" 
       android:duration="200"
       android:fillBefore="false"
       android:fillAfter="true" 
       android:valueType="floatValue"
       android:valueFrom="0.0"
       android:valueTo="1.0"
       android:fillEnabled="true" />

    <!-- погуглите как перевести translate с delta к objectAnimator-y -->
    <objectAnimator 
       android:interpolator="@anim/decelerate_quint" 
       android:duration="350"
       android:fillBefore="true"
       android:fillAfter="true"
       android:fromYDelta="8.000004%" 
       android:toYDelta="0.0"
       android:fillEnabled="true" />
</set>
```